# setState in componentWillMount doesn't reflect in componentWillMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making an ajax request In my componentWillMount function of react component. I have a state variable. I set the state of this variable as the response of the ajax call.

```
this.setState({state_variable: response})
```

Now in my componentDidMount function I am trying to console.log the value of state_variable. Ideally I should get the value of state_variable as what I have set above as response. But in console I see value printed as empty array which was the initialized value of state_variable.

Why componentDidMount now able to get the value I set? What am I doing wrong

Comment: can you show the entire react component

Answer (score 2):

Your ajax calls usually live in componentDidMount, not componentWillMount. The reason for that is that you don't want a call in an unmounted component, and you're making an assumption that the data is not returned before the component mounts.

I'm sure everything is running fine, you're just probably logging before the componentWillMount ajax call has returned. Instead of doing that, do something like:

```
$.ajax({
  // call parameters go here
}).then(function(response) {
  this.setState({ state_variable: response });
})

now do your logging inside of render instead:

render() {
  console.log(this.state.state_variable)
  // normal render jsx here
}
```

render will re-execute when the setState call is complete, so you should then get a good log.

Comment: I am logging it out in componentDidMount which executes after componentWillMount. It should get logged, right?

Comment: Not necessarily, it’s asynchronous, so componentDidMount won’t wait for your Ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think that the AJAX call will have completed by the time that `componentDidMount()` runs? `componentWillMount()` executes immediately before the first `render()` while `componentDidMount()` executes immediately *after* the first `render()`. So there isn't really enough time for your AJAX call to complete and update your state in the time it takes for the lifecycle to execute.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle

Comment: What should I do then? If I don't make the ajax call in componentWillMount then my component won't have data in it while rendering

Comment: @ArbitB render some kind of placeholder, or don't render anything at all, until you get the data. But there's no getting around waiting for an AJAX call, and that's something you need to design around.

Answer (score 0):

ComponentWillMount is intended to be used as an equivalent  lifecycle method to componentDidMount on server rendered react. There is not meant to be a garuntee it will finish first. The react style would be to set a loading property from your async call and render a loading ui until the request is finished.